# CodeIgniter pagination returns correct limit, but has same content each page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

The issue faced by the poster in [codeigniter pagination - results remain same on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416305/codeigniter-pagination-results-remain-same-on-every-page) is exactly where I find myself currently. Using the following code below, I'm returning a listing of all db table items but only getting the 10 results of the 1st paginated page on every subsequent page;

**Articlelist.php (controller)**

```
 //Get Article listing from DB table
 function index($page='')
 {
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'articlelist/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->article_model->record_count();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['results'] = $this->article_model->getList($page * $config['per_page']);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('articles_list', $data);
 }
```

**Article_model.php**

```
//COUNT ALL ARTICLES IN DB TABLE
    function record_count()
    {
      return $this->db->count_all('articles');
    }

    //GET ALL ARTICLES BY ID
    function getList($limit)
    {
       $limit = 10;
       $this->db->limit($limit);
       $query = $this->db->get('articles');

           if($query->num_rows() > 0)
           {
              foreach ($query->result() as $row)
              {
                $data[] = $row;
              }
                return $data;
            }
                return false;                 
    }
```

Resulting in the following views (and notice in the URL bar that returned identical results);
[image: query result return page 1]

....and so on...

[image: query result return page 2]

**...and (annoyingly) so on...**
[image: query result return page 3]

it's annoying simply for the fact that the pagination functionality is delivered without a hitch, and yet, the return of results from the `articles` DB never deviate from those ten returned results. Is there something I'm missing? **Of course** the sustained consultation within the 3.0.6 documentation didn't shake loose any insight on my current issue. Stumped...even tried removing the `return false;` from the end of my `function getList`, but, to no avail. Trying to remain patient and examine alternate code formatting, but this is the most stable of what was written previously.

And to those who might see something based on the loaded views' `foreach`;

**articles_list.php**

```
<?php
echo '<div class="content_bottom">';
echo '<div class="grid_1_of_2 box">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<div class="span_1_of_3_text2">';

if (!empty($results) && isset($results) && count($results) > 0){
  foreach ($results as $data){
    echo '<h3>Title:&nbsp;<a title="Click Here For Content" href="'?><?php echo base_url().'articlelist/view/'.$data->article_id.'">'. $data->title. '</a><br>Author:&nbsp;'.$data->name.'<br>Category:&nbsp;'.$data->category.'<br>Clicks:&nbsp;'.$data->clicks.'</h3><hr>';
  } 
} 
else
{
  echo '<p><font face="arial black" size="5" color="#0000CC">No Articles.</font></p>';
}
echo '<div id="pagination"><ul class="tsc_pagination tsc_paginationA tsc_paginationA01">'.$links.'</ul></div>';

echo '</div></div></div>';
?>
```

Hopefully **THAT** should be enough to go on.

*UPDATE**

I want to thank @pradeep for his efforts, which is helping point me to the possibility that this is a routing-based issue. The route for the article listing page is set as `$route['articlelist'] = 'articlelist/index';`. My misery index is heightened by the fact that I'm really not shaking much loose consulting the docs and have been ruthlessly searching down other documentation clarification. And to compound all this, the article URL redirection to view the referenced content embedded in the link works **flawlessly**. And as I'm able to add/edit/delete content, this is the only element sticking in my craw as of present.

**An "Oh...My Aching Head" Update**

Using the solution proffered by @Sonu Bamniya;

```
function index()
 {
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('articlelist/index/');
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('articles')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['results'] = $this->article_model->getList($page , $config['per_page']);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view('articles_list', $data);
 }
```

with the end results being;
[image: 1st page article list results]

**1st Page Results**

[image]

**2nd Page Results**

These results are completely identical to my previous coding further up in the post. I've even gone so far as to re-comb documentation searching for the needle to pierce this ballooning issue.
**`What am I missing?!?!? (pounds skull)`**

**CAPITULATION**

As I have to cede to practicality, for the time being, I'm counting out the totality of the content in the `articles` table and listing it to the page  without limit (as I don't have thousands of articles at the moment). I'm cutting myself slack by placing a `Back To Top` link at page bottom. I'm sure I'll have figured out a pagination solution before I get up to over one hundred articles. I'm so sick of wrestling with this, I'm just going to skip it for awhile. **;{**

Comment: its because you are setting`$limit = 10;` in your model, so `limit always updated to 0 to 10`

Answer (score 0):

its because you are setting `$limit = 10;` in your model, so `limit always updated to 0 to 10;`.

change your controller part:

```
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['results'] = $this->article_model->getList($page , $config['per_page']);
```

and in model fetch data using

```
function getList($page='0' , $limit='10')
{
 $this->db->limit($limit, $page);
 $query = $this->db->get('articles');

   if($query->num_rows() > 0)
   {
      foreach ($query->result() as $row)
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sonu Bamniya for your contribution, but I'm still getting the same result. I'll post an update using this code you contributed to chronicle my progress with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

$config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;

Check this in the config

Answer (score -2):

Use `POST` instead of `GET` in model and controller.

Comment: There is no need to do so.